# After upgrade flutter 3.3.10 to flutter 3.10.2, cannot get firebase_auth building anymore

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

After upgrade flutter 3.3.10 to flutter 3.10.2, cannot get firebase_auth running anymore.

I did upgrade to the latest version of flutter, after that my project, using firebase_auth is not building anymore.
This is a very simplified version of the bigger project, still having this issue.

- /C:/Users/gerdd/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.8.0/lib/src/method_channel/method_channel_firebase.dart:188:23: Error: A non-null value must be returned since the return type 'FirebaseAppPlatform' doesn't allow null.
- 'FirebaseAppPlatform' is from 'package:firebase_core_platform_interface/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart' ('/C:/Users/gerdd/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/firebase_core_platform_interface-4.8.0/lib/firebase_core_platform_interface.dart').
  firebase_core_platform_interface.dart:1
  FirebaseAppPlatform app([String name = defaultFirebaseAppName]) {
  I do get the following errors :

What is going wrong here, is there something I can do to get this project building again.

main.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './firebase_options.dart';
import './services/auth.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);

  runApp(DemoProject());
}

class DemoProject extends StatelessWidget {
  DemoProject({super.key});
  final AuthBase auth = Auth();

  Future<void> _signInAnonymously() async {
    try {
      await auth.signInAnonymously();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  Future<void> _signOut() async {
    try {
      await auth.signOut();
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'DemoProject',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.indigo,
        ),
        home: StreamBuilder<User>(
            stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
                User? user = snapshot.data;
                if ((user == null) || (user.uid == null)) {
                  return Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                      title: const Text('HomePage'),
                      centerTitle: true,
                    ),
                    body: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          TextButton(
                            onPressed: _signInAnonymously,
                            style: TextButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.lime.shade300),
                            child: const Text(
                              'Go anonymous',
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                }
                return Scaffold(
                  appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Homepage'), actions: <Widget>[
                    TextButton(
                        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                        ),
                        onPressed: _signOut,
                        child: const Text('Logout',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.white))),
                  ]),
                );
              }
              return const Scaffold(
                body: Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                ),
              );
            }));
  }
}
```

auth.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as firebaseauthorization;

class User {
  User({required this.uid});
  final String? uid;
}

abstract class AuthBase {
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged;
  Future<User> currentUser();
  Future<User> signInAnonymously();
  Future<void> signOut();
}

class Auth implements AuthBase {
  final _firebaseAuth = firebaseauthorization.FirebaseAuth.instance;

  User _userFromFirebase(firebaseauthorization.User? user) {
    if (user == null) {
      return User(uid: null);
    }
    return User(uid: user.uid);
  }

  @override
  Stream<User> get onAuthStateChanged {
    //return _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebase);
    return _firebaseAuth.authStateChanges().map(_userFromFirebase);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> currentUser() async {
    final user = _firebaseAuth.currentUser;
    return _userFromFirebase(user);
  }

  @override
  Future<User> signInAnonymously() async {
    final authResult = await _firebaseAuth.signInAnonymously();
    return _userFromFirebase(authResult.user);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOut() async {
    await _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```